# QGraphicsItemAnimation: How to indicate rotation point using setRotationAt

Tags: qt

When I use `QGraphicsItemAnimation::setRotationAt()` function to rotate a `QGraphicsItem` for an animation, the original point is always left top point of the item.

So I tried `QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint()` to make the rotation point to be at right top. But it still doesn't work. Is there any way to rotate the item itself at the right top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
     mAnimation->setTranslationAt(i / 1000.0, size.w, 0);
     mAnimation->setRotationAt(i / 1000.0, qreal(i / 1000.0 * angle));
     mAnimation->setTranslationAt(i / 1000.0, -size.w, 0);
}
```

Here is the answer i found, when set frames of the item, need to translate the original point before rotation, and translate it back.